# Using Variables for Column Names when Querying Parse.com Database

Tags: parse-platform

I have two Parse.com classes.  I retrieve an array of values from Class1.  The values are the names of the parse.com columns in Class2.  After retrieving the desired object from Class2, I want to loop through getting the appropriate columns in Class2 like this:

```
        Parse.initialize("KsUhcunt9PkSkvyRWXAeL", "ykLWdyBk6wAmOPC");
    var CheckWait = Parse.Object.extend("CheckWait");
    var query = new Parse.Query(CheckWait);
        query.equalTo("objectId", "oMP9qf7MAj");
    query.first({
    success: function(object) {
    $(".success").show();  
    var test = object.get("myArray[1]");    
    },
```

OK.  So, if I replace   myArray[1]   with the appropriate column name, it retrieved the desired data.  I tested the value contained in   myArray[1]    and it does contain the correct column name.  If i set another variable  = myArray[1]  parse.com still returns "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of `myArray[1]` is a string "nickname", then the following are equivalent:

```
var nick1 = object.get("nickname");
var nick2 = object.get(myArray[1]);
```

The issue is that you passed the string `"myArray[1]"` instead of the expression `myArray[1]`.